# headless-selenium-for-win install issues

Tags: selenium, github, selenium-webdriver, browser, command-line

I am trying to download and install https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win to use Headless Chrome and Firefox on windows.  As the new headless browsers built within FF and Chrome do not support extensions.
I keep getting:

```
C:\Users\Dan >pip install -U git+https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win.git
  Cloning https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win.git to c:\users\Dan\appdata\local\temp\pip-6wiag0j8-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Dan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-6wiag0j8-build\\setup.py'
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-6wiag0j8-build\
```

My question is, why is this not installing correctly?  Also, is it likely this method will allow extensions in Chrome or is that just the downsides of using headless browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install C++ project as a pip install. This is not going to work. You can download the compiled exe from their releases

https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win/releases

Extract the `headless_ie_selenium.exe` from above in system path. Then run something like below to get to Firefox

```
import os
os.environ["HEADLESS_DRIVER"] = "geckodriver.exe"
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox("headless_ie_selenium.exe")
```

PS: Since I don't have Windows, can't test the above code but if you read the documentation this is what the documentation says

> Selenium uses "drivers" to control web browsers. They are standalone executables driving browsers. headless_ie_selenium.exe by default looks for the IE driver in PATH, but it can be instructed to use other drivers as well. All command line arguments are forwarded to the driver, so the HEADLESS_DRIVER environment variable is used to specify the driver. Put the driver in one of the PATH directories.
>
> Set the HEADLESS_DRIVER environment variable to geckodriver.exe for headless Firefox.

Comment: It is giving me: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'headless_ie_selenium.exe'
I am using a virtual env.  Usually putting the headless executable in Anaconda folder resolves any pathing issues at least with gecko and Chromedriver but not in this case.  How do I manually add pathing to C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3

Comment: import os
os.environ["HEADLESS_DRIVER"] = "geckodriver.exe"
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox("headless_ie_selenium.exe")
driver.close()
The above worked for Chromedriver.  I also tried doing the full directory path C:\Users\Dan\Anaconda3\headless-selenium-for-win-v1-4\headless_ie_selenium.exe and it said The directory name is invalid

Comment: https://ibb.co/iy44Rv .  https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win/issues/17 .  As you can see I have to use the directory path.  Also from github if you click image, you can see that it's not acting as it should.  Any ideas why that is?